# How to change bundles.php file name in symfony Flex?

Tags: symfony4, symfony-flex

I want to change the name of bundle.php file, and configure flex to add bundles to my new file while executing composer req. is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, while you can change the name of the bundles php file that is being included in your `Kernel.php` under `registerBundles` function. The flex composer plugin will **NOT** detect it because the file name is hard coded in the flex source code [here](https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/b22b02a6909b3daf13a118abc8a442c2dd7dfc21/src/Configurator/BundlesConfigurator.php#L103)